# How to print in console a tree horizontally with links using c

Tags: c, tree, console, drawing, binary-tree

I'm reposting my question (obviously not enough information). I'd like to print a given binary tree horizontally in C *with links* between nodes.
I've done it without links; when I tried to do it with links it really got messed up.

PS: More explanations in the images [Click here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZKXZ.png) and here's the structure I work with:

```
typedef struct node{
   int val;            // value of the node
   struct node *left;  // left node
   struct node *right; // right node
}node;
```

And here's the function I wrote that can draw the tree with blanks and no links between nodes:

```
#define space 5

//secondary function
void draw_tree_hor2(node *tree, int distance)
{
    // stopping condition
    if (tree== NULL)
        return;

    // increase spacing
    distance += space;

    // start with right node
    draw_tree_hor2(tree->right, distance);

    // print root after spacing

    printf("\n");

    for (int i = space; i < distance; i++)
        printf(" ");

    printf("%d\n", tree->value);

    // go to left node
    draw_tree_hor2(tree->left, distance);
}

//primary fuction
void draw_tree_hor(node *tree)
{
   //initial distance is 0
    draw_tree_hor2(tree, 0);
}
```

If the information that i gave aren't enough please tell me...

Comment: I guess this is homework since there was a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41090663/how-to-print-in-console-a-tree-horizotally-with-links-using-c-language#41090663) with identical graphic recently.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  It looks as if you might've learned about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  It also looks like you asked this question before as a different user ([How to print in a console a tree horizontally with links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41090663/how-to-print-in-console-a-tree-horizotally-with-links-using-c-language), as a different user.  This question has at least got some code which the other was signally lacking.  Can we be sure, though, that you won't simply delete your account and/or question this time?

Comment: no it's me that post that question too, by mistake i deleted the accout so created a new one and repost the same question here with more details...

Comment: Please show sample data, the output you get without the links, and the output you'd like with the links.  It's hard to know what you want to see if you don't show us.

Comment: We don't want to have to go look at images — it is text output; show it in the question!  Treat it as code.

Comment: sorry i'm new here,can you tell me how to do that

Comment: I agree with all the comments here, you should take more time to elaborate your question.

Comment: To be clear: your output is missing the `/` and `\\`, otherwise it works as desired?

Comment: What is the minimumsize of the tree (0, 1, etc.)?  What is the maximum (7,  1000s?)

Comment: @chux the problem that i face is how to insert these / or \ ... and about the size, what do you mean (number of nodes ?..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I threw something together real quick, seems to work. Might want to add some checks to prevent `depth` from exceeding `path` size etc. Should get you started at least.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define space 5


typedef struct node{
   int value;          // value of the node
   struct node *left;  // left node
   struct node *right; // right node
}node;

//secondary function
void draw_tree_hor2(node *tree, int depth, char *path, int right)
{
    // stopping condition
    if (tree== NULL)
        return;

    // increase spacing
    depth++;

    // start with right node
    draw_tree_hor2(tree->right, depth, path, 1);

    if(depth > 1)
    {
        // set | draw map
        path[depth-2] = 0;

        if(right)
            path[depth-2] = 1;
    }

    if(tree->left)
        path[depth-1] = 1;

    // print root after spacing
    printf("\n");

    for(int i=0; i<depth-1; i++)
    {
      if(i == depth-2)
          printf("+");
      else if(path[i])
          printf("|");
      else
          printf(" ");

      for(int j=1; j<space; j++)
      if(i < depth-2)
          printf(" ");
      else
          printf("-");
    }

    printf("%d\n", tree->value);

    // vertical spacers below
    for(int i=0; i<depth; i++)
    {
      if(path[i])
          printf("|");
      else
          printf(" ");

      for(int j=1; j<space; j++)
          printf(" ");
    }

    // go to left node
    draw_tree_hor2(tree->left, depth, path, 0);
}

//primary fuction
void draw_tree_hor(node *tree)
{
    // should check if we don't exceed this somehow..
    char path[255] = {};

    //initial depth is 0
    draw_tree_hor2(tree, 0, path, 0);
}



node n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7;

int main()
{
  n1.value = 1;
  n2.value = 2;
  n3.value = 3;
  n4.value = 4;
  n5.value = 5;
  n6.value = 6;
  n7.value = 7;

  n1.right = &n2;
  n1.left = &n3;
  //n2.right = &n4;
  //n2.left = &n5;
  n3.right = &n6;
  n3.left = &n7;

  n2.right = &n3;
  n2.left = &n3;

  draw_tree_hor(&n1);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
>gcc test_graph.c && a

          +----6
          |
     +----3
     |    |
     |    +----7
     |
+----2
|    |
|    |    +----6
|    |    |
|    +----3
|         |
|         +----7
|
1
|
|    +----6
|    |
+----3
     |
     +----7
```

Comment: It works perfectly , Thank you sir. I'm trying to understand the process of the algorithm, as it seems that you used the idea of path and and depth (i didn't think about it) , thanks again :)

Comment: You're welcome :) The horizontal lines were pretty easy. The verticals were a bit harder. `path` was probably a bad name for the variable. It basically saves at what depths do we need vertical lines in the current row. If we're to the right of something, we'll need a `|` one level above until we reach the node. If there's a subnode to the left we'll need `|`'s at the current depth until we reach a node etc.

Comment: There's a minor issue with the code. Whenever there's an access to path[depth-2], we must first make sure depth>1. In particular

if (depth>1) { /* <-- This check is needed */
    path[depth-2] = 0;

        if(right)
            path[depth-2] = 1;
}